# Java Calendar add hour issue getting time in millis

Tags: java, date, time, calendar

I have this snippet here:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("calendar " + cal.getTime());
    System.out.println("ms calendar" + cal.getTime().getTime());
    long ms0 = cal.getTime().getTime();
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);
    System.out.println("calendar one hour less " + cal.getTime());
    System.out.println("ms calendar one hour less " + cal.getTime().getTime());
    long ms1 = cal.getTime().getTime();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(t0-t1);
    System.out.println("result " + cal.getTime());
```

I was expecting to have  just one hour of difference between the two dates.
Instead of that I'm getting this weird result:

```
calendar Wed Sep 23 09:51:36 CEST 2015
ms calendar 1442994696681
calendar one hour less Wed Sep 23 08:51:36 CEST 2015
ms calendar one hour less 1442991096681
result Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 CET 1970
```

What am I getting wrong? 
How should I get just one hour of difference, as I see in the Dates?

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You _do_ get different millis: 144299**4696681** vs 144299**1096681**.

Comment: you should look over your problem twice before asking a question that needs no answere

Comment: Well, I do have a problem. I've edited the question...

Comment: Well how about looking into the documentation for once? The Calendar object starts with the defined epoch, therefore your output is epoch+ 1hour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
System.out.println("milis restantes:"+ (ms0-ms1));
```

Result in:

```
milis restantes:3600000
```

Your program is working as desired

**EDIT:**
With you edited question, you need to understand that Calendar starts to count milis from **epoch**, witch in this case is :
Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970
So adding an hour to this date will result in
Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 CET 1970

If you want to check this behaviour:

```
cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
  System.out.println("result new Calendar " + cal.getTime());
```

Result:

```
result new Calendar Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually my problem was a little different. Please, see the edited question...